# SPARQL - Extracting Director and Starring from DBPedia

Tags: sparql

Could anyone please help me with this code. It doesn't come out with any output but with no error.

```
q = """SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?abstract ?director ?starring
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties> rdfs:label ?label.
    ?label dbo:abstract ?abstract. 
    ?label dbo:director ?director. 
    ?label dbo:starring ?starring. 
    FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
    FILTER (lang(?abstract) = "en")
}"""

from textwrap import wrap

for result in query(q): 
    print(result['label'],
      "\n----Director----\n",result['director'],
      "\n----Starring----\n",result['starring'],
      "\n----Abstract----\n",
      "\n".join(wrap(result['abstract'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties>` is the entity which has a Label, Abstract, Director, Star, etc.

The Label of that entity is a literal, and it has no Director, Star, Abstract, etc.

Try [changing your query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fabstract%20%3Fdirector%20%3Fstarring%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Adirector%20%3Fdirector%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Astarring%20%3Fstarring%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) to --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?abstract ?director ?starring
WHERE 
  {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties> 
       rdfs:label   ?label ;
       dbo:abstract ?abstract ;
       dbo:director ?director ;
       dbo:starring ?starring 
    FILTER ( lang(?label) = "en" )
    FILTER ( lang(?abstract) = "en" )
  }
```

-- and see [results from DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fabstract%20%3Fdirector%20%3Fstarring%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Adirector%20%3Fdirector%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Astarring%20%3Fstarring%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

DBpedia Live delivers nothing for the query above -- because the descriptions of films vary.  [Making some things optional](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fabstract%20%3Fdirector%20%3Fstarring%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%3Flabel%20%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20dbo%3Adirector%20%3Fdirector%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20dbo%3Astarring%20%3Fstarring%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) will get you more [results on DBpedia Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fabstract%20%3Fdirector%20%3Fstarring%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%3Flabel%20%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20dbo%3Adirector%20%3Fdirector%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSeven_Beauties%3E%20dbo%3Astarring%20%3Fstarring%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?abstract ?director ?starring
WHERE
{
             <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties> rdfs:label   ?label 
  OPTIONAL { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties> dbo:abstract ?abstract }
  OPTIONAL { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties> dbo:director ?director }
  OPTIONAL { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Seven_Beauties> dbo:starring ?starring }
  FILTER ( lang(?label) = "en" )
  FILTER ( lang(?abstract) = "en" )
}
```

Comment: My original code somehow quite similar with yours above witch i have to put the URI link four times to extract the abstract, director and starring.
So, then i try to adjust the code which need to put just one link URI for label, so that it can extract the abstract, director and starring. That's come out with no output as per my question above.

Comment: Thank you so much TallTed. I got the output with your code editted. Really appreciate it